# TCL HTML File Viewer

Tags: html, mysql, tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to convert data from MySQL to HTML by using TCL.

1. The real problem converting mysql data to html,
2. showing that html in TCL viewer,
3. can I host IE inside TCL canvas or some widget anything etc. I want to develop adhoc HTML-reporting module for an assignment.

In short: I want to load/open/view HTML file in TCL. Any samples would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you just open the HTML in the web browser?

Comment: If that was the case, I wouldn't have asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

While you *can't* just make IE render on a canvas — too many things interact in unpleasant ways to make that impossible — you may well be able to use [OpTcl](http://wiki.tcl.tk/optcl) to embed it in a window, which you can then put in a canvas if you choose.

Here's the informative example from that page:

```
package require optcl

optcl::new -window .htm {http://wiki.tcl.tk}
.htm config -width 800 -height 600
pack .htm
```

This will manufacture an instance of the COM object for handling an HTTP URL (in this case, `http://wiki.tcl.tk`) and embed it in a Tk widget (`.htm`). If you were going to embed it in a canvas, you'd do:

```
package require optcl
canvas .canv
optcl::new -window .canv.htm http://wiki.tcl.tk
.canv create window 0 0 -anchor nw -window .canv.htm
pack .canv
```

Well, that's the minimum. You'd really do a bit more (adding scrollbars, etc.)

There's a more [extensive example](http://wiki.tcl.tk/4094) on the Wiki too. (This doesn't appear to be a task for Tcom; that's designed to allow Tcl to interact with COM, but not really to allow Tk to embed widgets defined by it.) Be aware that I've not tested this on recent Windows systems or with recent versions of Tcl/Tk.

Comment: The other main part of your question — converting query results to HTML — really should be covered by existing questions. (I urge you not to use a browser directly written in Tcl; though people have done that sort of thing a few times, they're badly out of date and embedding IE will give happier results.)

Comment: Thank you, it was beneficial. One more thing, how to embed IE ?

Comment: @Anonymous That's what my answer is about! It does COM magic…

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to TCL. Its syntax confuses me most of the times, although I've been programming in Microsoft technologies for a long time. Thank you Donal, it was really helpful.

Comment: Dear Donal, I've been trying to download OPTCL somehow, but I cannot download it: "http://wiki.tcl.tk/1822"
Please if you know about any alternate link, please do let me know. thanks

Comment: @donalfellows Afternoon Donal, sorry to open a question from the past, but I found some difficulty in understanding your answer. Was I wrong in assuming that these commands were in R?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to convert data from MySQL to HTML by using TCL.

With data from a table, you may be better off using the [TkTable](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1877) widget, sidestepping the conversion to HTML entirely.

> I want to load/open/view HTML file in TCL.

There is a Tk-widget called [TkHTML](http://tkhtml.tcl.tk/tkhtml.html), which seems like it'll do just what you need.